# mercurial error code :255 , having problems cloning

Tags: mercurial

I'm having problems while cloning a repository .

```
   % hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central
```

im getting back this error

```
   destination directory: mozilla-central
   abort: Access is denied: 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\mozilla-central'
```

Can anyone help me and tell me why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running the hg clone command in a directory where you don't have permission to create files

Also you need to add the destination directory

Example :

```
% hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central newDirectory
```

Comment: Looks like you're running the hg clone command in a directory where you don't have permission to create files.